# Getting hostAddress in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I need to send a file from group owner to a connected(through `WiFi` Direct) device. I find the device by Service discovery. In `onConnectionAvailable` function i can find group owner address by:

```
String host = info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
```

But how do i find the address of other device?

Comment: You can see my answer about this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24160775/1340588).
Hope it helps you.